# How to change ng-class trough router controller?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui, angular-ui-router

This is my html:

```
<div class="navigation">
    <ul class="nav nav-tabs">
        <li ng-class="tab1">
            <a ui-sref="general" ng-click="tab1='active'; tab2=''; tab3=''">General</a>
        </li>
        <li ng-class="tab2">
            <a ui-sref="corrective" ng-click="tab1=''; tab2='active'; tab3=''">Corrections</a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

And thats my js:

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', ["ui.router"])
myApp.config(function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider){
$urlRouterProvider.otherwise("/general");
$stateProvider
.state('general', {
  url: "/general",
  templateUrl: "template/general.html",
  controller: function($scope) {
    $scope.tab1='active';
  }
})
.state('corrective', {
  url: "/corrective",
  templateUrl: "template/corrective.html",
  controller: function($scope) {
    $scope.tab2='active';
  }
})
```

});

Sory, I'm beginer and I need to change ng-class which depend from route. What's the problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Right now you're giving the `<li>` the class `tab1`. That is likely not what you want to do. Instead, you could do:

```
<li ng-class="{'active': tab1=='active'}">
```

This means: Set the class to `active`, assuming the condition `tab1=='active'` is fulfilled.

In my applications, I do this in another fashion, though. I have a global function defined in `app.run()`:

```
$rootScope.isActive = function() {
  return Array.prototype.some.call(arguments, function(arg) {
    return $state.is(arg);
  });
}
```

And whenever I want to apply a class conditionally based on state, I do:

```
<li ng-class="{'active' : isActive('someState','anotherState','moreStates')}">
```

As a bonus, this also allows the same element to have the `active` class applied for several states. In your example, you would only need

```
<li ng-class="{'active' : isActive('general')}">
```

And

```
 <li ng-class="{'active' : isActive('corrective')}">
```

On top of that, there's no longer a need for you `ng-click`s.